# What is the issue with this sentence?

Tags: sentence

What is wrong with this sentence.

> 'Keep moving please. If everyone was to stand there, how would the rest of the people manage to get past?'

Comment: Some might say that the subjunctive 'were' rather than 'was' is required, but the sentence is logically (as opposed to grammatically) flawed. Taking 'everyone' in its strict rather than its loose (lots of people) sense, there **is no** 'rest of the people'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So it's sort of a riddle or something?

Comment: My guess would be that to ask people to 'keep moving' implies they already are moving, yet the next sentence assumes they are standing still.

Comment: We spent about two minutes on 'nonsense sentences' in junior school. I suppose this was intended to show us that even if you get all the vocabulary, spelling, grammar and punctuation right, you can still come up with something untrue, in poor style, or just nonsensical. This was one of the examples of a nonsense statement (there were worse!) Lewis Carroll was brillig at this stuff (_his_ examples are worth reading), and 'This statement is false' is a classic mind-bender beloved of philosophers.

Comment: Do you know that there is in fact a problem with the sentence? or are you not sure, and it's possibly correct anyway? If this were a logic question, I would say that Everyone is incorrect, since some people are 'trying to get past'

Comment: I think it's as @EdwinAshworth says: it's a 'nonsense' sentense. If 'everyone' is standing there, we wouldn't then have 'the rest of the people', would we?

Comment: It's just lazy thinking/construction. They meant to say something like "Don't stop there. If others also stop there, then it will make it difficult to get past." But they tried to do bring in the "if everyone did that..." argument against antisocial behavior, and then the whole thing just blew up in their mouth.

"Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded." - Yogi Berra

Comment: @Elijah YB was exaggerating. They say it's not as bad as they say it is. [comment on the Irish Question some 20 years ago]

Comment: Isn't the use of "everyone" just a form of hyperbole? Sentences like this are not intended to be taken literally, any more than a warning that "you'll poke your eye out" is.